# Bulk-loading in monetdb with primary key constraint

Tags: sql, duplicates, primary-key, bulk-load, monetdb

I am trying to bulk-load a list of objects into a one-column (primary key) db. 
The only reason is to remove duplicates. I can't load the list in memory, because the file size is way greater than my memory size (I need around 10^14 insertions!).

I use monetdb's [COPY-INTO](http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/CopyInto) command, but I don't want it to fail when there is a duplicate. I want it to add everything that is not a duplicate and skip the duplicates.

Is there any way to do that with monetdb? Any other way?

Comment: Maybe you can add with duplicates and later query with distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy it first into a table without primary key constraint and afterwards remove the duplicates and alter the table to enforce the primary key constraint.